# Integrate CA certificate in helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

What is the best way to add a CA certificate to the kubernetes helm deployment of the Gitlab toolbox?

We have a Minio S3 server outside the Kubernetes cluster for backup purposes. The Minio has a self-signed certificate.

I need the CA certificate in the container of the Gitlab toolbox which was installed with the helm chart.

Currently I have edited the deployment by hand and added the certificate.

But this process has to be done again with every update by helm.

So I am wondering what is the right way to add the CA certificate to the container?